# How to config Squid SSL bump to let Paloalto PA series firewall recognize App-ID

Tags: proxy

A Paloalto firewall(PA-2050,POS 4.1x) was capable of recognizing the websites which users are visiting(thru http/https) then flag them with a App-ID and apply application control on the traffic, for instance blocking all webmail/file sharing/social media... etc.

But PA-2050 can only recognize those traffic visiting websites with https as "SSL" after we setup a Squid proxy 3.4 with SSL bump before the firewall.  This crippling the application control mechanism of PA firewall.

Anyone knows how to config Squid 3.4 (or PA-2050) so as to recover the application control capability on https traffic thru Squid proxy?

Comment: update our newest findings: We use "NO_TLSv1" in Squid SSL bump directives to compatible with many e-banking websites that only accept SSLv3.  But that force all https traffic use SSLv3 that don't have a "server_name" extension. It looks like PA firewall need the "server_name" extention to know where you are going when ssl decryption function is not enabled, missing that information to judge so PA can only treat the https request as generic SSL application instead more specific ap like gmail/google drive etc.

Comment: So a feasible Squid SSL Bump configuration(good for both TLS & SSLv3) is what we need now.